# Creating tables with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a table with Angular.js which will have cell's spanning many rows.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/famedriver/kDrc6/

Example data

```
var data = [{Colors: ["red","green","blue"]}]
```

Expected output

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Colors</td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>green</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

I have it working by using the `ng-show` directive.  But that still renders an extra cell, just hidden.  It would be ideal to have the table properly rendered.

`ng-switch`, as mentioned, won't work in certain elements with strict parsing (ie: a table which only allows certain tags)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering question using more recent version of Angular.

As Andrew Joslin wrote, the [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) hides the element (it applies `display: none`). [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) removes non-matching elements instead of just hiding them. But it also requires extra element for `switch-when` expression.

Since the last answer, the [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) has become a part of Angular, you no longer need an external library.

```js
(function(win) {
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("Tester", function($scope) {
      $scope.data = {
        Colors: ["red", "green", "blue"]
      }
    })
}(window));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <h1>old code converted</h1>
  <p>Just converted to a newer AngularJS.</p>
  <table border="1" ng-controller="Tester">
    <tbody ng-repeat='(what,items) in data'>
      <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td rowspan="{{items.length}}" ng-show="$first">{{what}}</td>
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h1>solution via ng-if</h1>
  <table border="1" ng-controller="Tester">
    <tbody ng-repeat='(what,items) in data'>
      <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td rowspan="{{items.length}}" ng-if="$first">{{what}}</td>
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Normally you could use [ng-switch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) for something like this, which conditionally adds/removes things from the DOM, unlike ng-show/ng-hide which just hide/show things.

But ng-switch doesn't play nice with tables because it requires an extra element for the switch statement.

Luckily, someone made a directive called ['if'](https://github.com/tigbro/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter/blob/master/src/main/webapp/utils/if.js) which just takes one attribute on an element and conditionally adds/removes it from the DOM.  It's genius :-).

Here's an example of it (look in the 'Resources' panel on the side, I included it from github). http://jsfiddle.net/5zZ7e/.

I also showed how you can make your controllers without global variables in there.

Comment: An `if` statement... how useful & elegant.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is your JavaScript code, i.e. the Controller, an anonymous function? I am not disputing it, but want to learn.