# Error: Argument is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, playframework

Using AngularJS with Scala Play, I'm getting this error.

> Error: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

I'm trying to create a table consisting of the days of the week.

Please take a look at my code. I had checked the name of the Controller, but that seems correct. Note: Code used from this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367769/creating-tables-with-angular-js)

**index.scala.html**

```
@(message: String)

@main("inTime") {

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    </head>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="1">
    <tbody ng-repeat='(what,items) in data'>
      <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <td ngm-if="$first" rowspan="{{items.length}}">{{what}}</td>
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</html> 
}
```

**MainCtrl.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('[myApp]', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {
            Colors: ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
        }
    });
}());
```

Comment: In html where you have used `ng-app` can you change it to `ng-app=myApp`

Comment: Got the same error @Chandermani

Comment: Have you tried removing the closure (IIFE) from the code? When I had this problem, it was because I had a PHP error in my javascript.

Comment: You can find out your problem, by this checklist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797874/930170

Comment: Confirm whether you have added MainCtrl.controller.js is added in BundleConfig.cs file

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Remove the `[]` from the name ([myApp]) of module

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

And add `ng-app="myApp"` to the html and it should work.

Comment: All I had to do to get it working was the second suggestion (i.e. set ng-app="myApp"). If I removed the [], I got another error.

Comment: Having the second parameter `[]` indicates that you are creating a new module.  Removing the second parameter indicates that you are retrieving an existing module.  So one possibility to check is if you are calling `angular.module` twice, both times including the second parameter.  If so, the later occurrence will overwrite the second, hiding any definitions of controllers up to that point.

Comment: When he says to remove the `[]` he's referring to the first parameter where the OP has `[myApp]` instead of `myApp`. He's not talking about the second parameter.

Comment: Check the name of your controller if you are using routes. The controller name in the route definition is case sensitive.

Answer (score 78):

**FIRST.**
check if you have correct `controller` in the route definitions, same as the controller names that you are defining

```
communityMod.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/members', {
        templateUrl: 'modules/community/views/members.html',
        controller: 'CommunityMembersCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/members'
      });
  }]);

communityMod.controller('CommunityMembersCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.name = 'Hello community';
    }]);
```

different controller names in this example will lead to errors, but this example is correct

**SECOND** check if you have imported your javascript file:

`<script src="modules/community/controllers/CommunityMembersCtrl.js"></script>`

Comment: In my experience, your "second" is always the problem. I often forget to import my controllers into `index.html`

Comment: It was the second one in my case as well, forgot to import the JS file...

Answer (score 26):

I had the same error message (in my case : "Argument 'languageSelectorCtrl' is not a function, got undefined").

After some tedious comparison with Angular seed's code, I found out that I had previously removed a reference to the controllers module in app.js. (spot it at https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js)

So I had this:

`angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.filters', 'MyApp.services', 'MyApp.directives'])`

This failed.

And when I added the missing reference:

`angular.module('MyApp', ['MyApp.filters', 'MyApp.services', 'MyApp.controllers', 'MyApp.directives'])`

The error message disappeared and Angular could instanciate the controllers again.

Comment: had the same problem, my issue was that I forgot to add my controller to the app module... why does this not happen automatically???  thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 16):

Some times this error is a result of **two** `ng-app` directives specified in the html.
In my case by mistake I had specified `ng-app` in my `html` tag and `ng-app="myApp"` in the `body` tag like this:

```
<html ng-app>
  <body ng-app="myApp"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: It happened to me when i did not add the injection to the myApp module.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 6):

This seriously took me 4 HOURS (including endless searches on SO) but finally I found it: by mistake (unintentionally) I added a space somewhere.

Can you spot it?

`angular.module('bwshopper.signup').controller('SignupCtrl ', SignupCtrl);`

So ... 4 hours later I saw that it should be:

`angular.module('bwshopper.signup').controller('SignupCtrl', SignupCtrl);`

Almost impossible to see with just the naked eye.

This stresses the vital importance of revision control (git or whatever) and unit/regression testing.

Comment: My answer was not an extra space but it lead me to my fix. I had `Controller` instead of `controller` and that was all it took.

Comment: And I named my file options-moda.controller.js but was looking for options-modal.controller.js   DOH!

Comment: Mine was because of I forgot to add .js in BundleConfig. Simple but frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same problem and in my case it was happening as a result of this problem:

I had the controllers defined in a separate module (called 'myApp.controllers') and injected to the main app module (called 'myApp') like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers'])
```

A colleague pushed another controller module in a separate file but with the exact same name as mine (i.e. 'myApp.controllers' ) which caused this error. I think because Angular got confused between those controller modules. However the error message was not very helpful in discovering what is going wrong.

Comment: This should get fixed by removing the second parameter in the module... To get the existing module using angular.module('myApp') without the second parameter. i.e. angular.module('myApp').contoller(...)

Answer (score 3):

In my case (having an overview page and an "add" page) I got this with my routing setup like below. It was giving the message for the AddCtrl that could not be injected...

```
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    redirectTo: '/overview'
  }).      
  when('/overview', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/overview.html',
    controller: 'OverviewCtrl'
  }).
  when('/add', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/add.html',
    controller: 'AddCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/overview'
  });
```

Because of the `when('/'` route all my routes went to the overview and the controller could not be matched on the /add route page rendering. This was confusing because I DID see the add.html template but its controller was nowhere to be found.

Removing the '/'-route when case fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I was receiving this error as well and tearing my hair out because it was causing my TFS builds to fail. Commenting out the '/' route fixed it for me as well. Now to figure out why!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in a submodule, don't forget to declare the module in main app.
ie :

```
<scrip>
angular.module('mainApp', ['subModule1', 'subModule2']);

angular.module('subModule1')
   .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.moduleName = 'subModule1';
   }]);
</script>
...
<div ng-app="mainApp">
   <div ng-controller="MyController">
   <span ng-bind="moduleName"></span>
</div>
```

If you don't declare subModule1 in mainApp, you will got a "[ng:areq] Argument "MyController" is not a function, got undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Уmed's second point was my pitfall but just for the record, maybe it's helping someone somewhere:

I had the same problem and just before I went nuts I discovered that I had forgotten to include my controller script.

As my app is based on ASP.Net MVC I decided to keep myself sane by inserting the following snippet in my **App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/app").Include(
                "~/app/app.js",
                "~/app/controllers/*.js",
                "~/app/services/*.js" ));
```

and in **Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
...
   @Scripts.Render("~/app")
...
</head>
```

Now I won't have to think about including the files manually ever again.
In hindsight I really should have done this when setting up the project...

Answer (score 1):

I got sane error with LoginController, which I used in main index.html.
I found two ways to resolve:

1. setting $controllerProvider.allowGlobals(), I found that comment in Angular [change-list](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3f2232b5a181512fac23775b1df4a6ebda67d018)
   "this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it in new ones!" original comment on Angular

   app.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
        $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
      }]);
2. wrong contructor of registering controller

before

```
LoginController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location'];
```

now

```
app.controller('LoginController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', LoginController]);
```

'app' come from app.js

```
var MyApp = {};
var app = angular.module('MyApp ', ['app.services']);
var services = angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with a big mistake:

```
appFormid.controller('TreeEditStepControlsCtrl', [$scope, function($scope){

}]);
```

You see ? i forgot the '' around the first $scope, the right syntax is of course:

```
appFormid.controller('TreeEditStepControlsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

A first error i didn't see immediatly was: "*$scope is not defined*", followed by "*Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TreeEditStepControlsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined*"

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a simple typo in `index.html`:

```
<script src="assets/javascript/controllers/questionssIndexController.js"></script>
```

that should have been

```
<script src="assets/javascript/controllers/questionsIndexController.js"></script>
```

without the extra `s` in the controller's name.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as enclosing your asset in " " and whatever needs quotes on the inside with ' '?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at('stylesheets/main.css')">
```

That could be causing some problems with parsing

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, I had to discover that I misspelled the name of the controller in the declaration of Angular routes:

```
.when('/todo',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/todo.html',
            controller: 'TodoCtrl'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's the Cache of the browser, using Chrome here. Simply check the "Disable cache" under Inspect (Element) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because this pops-up in Google when trying to find an answer to: "Error: Argument '' is not a function, got undefined".

It's possible that you are trying to create the same module twice.

> The angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and
>   retrieving AngularJS modules.
>
> **Passing one argument retrieves an existing angular.Module, whereas**
>   **passing more than one argument creates a new angular.Module**

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#overview

Example:

`angular.module('myApp', [])` Is used to create a module without injecting any dependencies.

`angular.module('myApp')` (Without argument) is used to get an existing module.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be *many working solutions* suggesting the error has *many actual causes*.

In my case I hadn't declared the controller in `app/index.html`:

```html
<scipt src="src/controllers/controller-name.controller.js"></script>
```

Error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and AngularJS is on its way out, but I want to add my answer anyway. In my case, I created a new file in Visual Studio Code but did not add the .js extension to my controller file name. That is what led to this error for me.