# Angularjs controller is showing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm using monaca ide for the development.

I'm trying to post the data from html to php page using angularjs, which gives me error
**Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'joinctrl' is not a function, got undefined** i don't know anything about angularjs, please help me with this, thank you for any help.

html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
        ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill();  // (Monaca enables StatusBar plugin by default)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">

    </ons-navigator> 
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<ons-page style="background:#5C2D50">
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal__content" ng-app=joinus ng-controller="joinctrl">
        <form>
        <h1>Join Us</h1>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"><br />
        <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" ng-model="password"><br />
        <input type="password"  placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="cpassword"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="creat" ng-submit="create()">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gos" onclick="myNavigator.popPage()"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left" id="bk"></span></div>
</ons-page>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('joinus', ['onsen']);

app.controller('joinctrl', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.create=function(){
       var request=$http({
           method:"post",
           url:"http://www.elunika.com/joinus.php",
           data:{
               email:$scope.email,
               password:$scope.password,
               cpassword:$scope.cpassword
           },
           headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
       });
   request.success(function(data){
       myNavigator.popPage();
   });
   request.error(function(data){
       alert("Error While Proccessing");
   })
   }
});
```

please let me know the mistakes i'm doing.

1. Please let me know that `<form>` needs to be used in html or not if i'm using angularjs.
2. Please let me know if i can use `alert` the same way we use in jquery.

once again thank you for any help.

Comment: You have to remove ng-click on submit & add it form as ng-submit="create()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `onsen` module dependency included in your `index.html` file?

Here is a [working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/HThaunlhNWfJ9aFaD1gK?p=preview) of your code, with the `onsen` excluded.

One could use a single `ng-app` at the `<html>` or `<body>` tags. Make sure to have a single `ng-app` attribute over the whole app.

As for:

1. You can use `<form>` like that.
2. You can.

:)

PS: The Plunker example I provided doesn't get the problem of `areq`, as you may see in browser's console.

Comment: it is showing the same error for me if i go without `onsen` but onsen is included because i'm working with onsen ui

Comment: Do you mention controller or app names anywhere else in your `html` file by any chance?

Comment: change `ng-app="joinus"` to `ng-app=joinus`

Comment: and in general, more clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289236/error-argument-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: and a check-sequence here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797756/how-to-find-a-reason-angularjs-argument-myctrl-is-not-a-function-got-undefin/26797874#26797874

Comment: i already checked that, that possibilities haven't resolved my query

Comment: i think everything is correct according to them, but this problem is still not getting resolved

Comment: is there more to the error that you posted? would you be so kind to update the question with an 'extended' error message? And also, the sequence of scripts inclusion in the `index.html` file.

Comment: Thank you. And what happens if you try to include these `ng-app=joinus ng-controller="joinctrl"` in the `<body>` tag of the index file? and remove them from where they currently are

Comment: well i can't do that because i have one more form which will also be included in the same then

Comment: you can nest controllers and could put a single `ng-app` at the `<html>` tag. Make sure to have a single ng-app over the whole app. And where do you include `angular.js` script? as well as `onsen.js`?

Comment: but if i try doing that also it shows multiple errors

Comment: loader.js is having everything in it

Comment: anyway thank you for the help and i appreciate for giving me your precious time.

Comment: it helped me alot, i inserted ng-app variable in the `<html>` tag and it worked. please edit your answer so thet i can select your answer as correct.

Comment: Done. Added a part about `ng-app` inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Form does need to be used when you are using AngularJS. It is the same way as you would for other frameworks. The way you added ng-click to the submit button is valid.
2. AngularJS is just a JavaScript framework. The way you used alerts is valid.

May I ask at what point/for what action do you get **Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'joinctrl' is not a function, got undefined**?

Comment: well as @nikolay answered about this, it is working fine in demo. but when i'm using it in monaca debugger, it is showing me such errors