# Argument '' is not a function got undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a new angularjs controller and this error just don't want to dissapear:

```
Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined
```

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Hello';
});
```

app.html.twig

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <h1> {{'{{ data }}' }}</h1>

</div>
```

I really don't understand what am I missing. I ve searched for this error, and I tried the solutions presented but I can not resolve it. Any ideas?

Comment: may be this what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895387/1054978

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: Error: \[ng:areq\] Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und)

Comment: Try: var app = angular.module('myApp', []); app.controller...

Comment: @RamsingNadeem still the same error..

Comment: @Mourya already checked that solution, but with not success. In my configuration I have: angular.module('myApp', []); And I access it only once so don't see the point

Comment: @IleNea you probably just didn't load the script with your defined controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289236/error-argument-is-not-a-function-got-undefined

Comment: @devqon and where this load is usually made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your own code. Please go through it and for more just go to  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZaI0sfAj8t3xMaaKyPbw?p=preview)

```
 //JS code
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = 'Hello';
    });




    //template code
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="AppController">
              <h1> {{data}}</h1>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: in the plunker it works but in my app it doesn't and I don't know why..

Comment: Are you closing your <div> tag properly?

Comment: Yes, yes.. @Jverma

Answer (score 0):

Try to create like this

```
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

    jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.data = 'Hello';
    });


<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{ data }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep it separate like this, it'll work

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**OR**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Hello';
});
```

Also this syntax is wrong but your error is not because of this

```
<h1> {{'{{ data }}' }}</h1>
```

**Change**

```
<h1> {{ data }}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 'Hello';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
      <h1> {{data}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

{{'{{ data }}' }} =======> {{data}}

I created a snippet with your provided code and jut this part in html and it's working now. Kindly check this answer.

Thank you.

Comment: still not working.. should I declared also in another place?

Comment: if you can provide your problem with a plunker that would be helpful for us to find out the issue.

Comment: markup structure fine? Because the code you provided is missing one closing div.